# Getting visual studio error An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v1': Could not find a part of the path 'C:\'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am getting error upon executing  debug test on my visual studio as following code.

Getting visual studio error An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v1': Could not find a part of the path 'C:\'.

I have used different computer and it works fine. Its only my computer is showing above error. I have also installed fresh copy of Visual community.

Does anyone have similar issue before? How to resolve this?

Comment: Is that the actual, full error message? Does your machine have a C: drive? Or is there actually a path that does not exist?

Comment: ------ Run test started ------
An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v1': Could not find a part of the path 'C:\'.
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:01.1736839)                   Yes,  I am running in windows computer. thank you.

Comment: Are you targeting different versions of .net?

Comment: Again, does your machine have a C: drive? Use ProcMon to see what the executor actually is trying to do.

Comment: Are your using Entity Framework ?

Comment: yes I am using  Entity Framework  6.1.3

Comment: Yes I have got c:

Comment: ProcMon seems the great tool, but don't know how to use it. how to monitor executor? Sorry for trouble everyone. Thank you.

Comment: what was issue?

Comment: Every time I try to run a debug test on Web api project using unit test. it shows above error in my PC. However it works on different computer.

Answer (score 0):

Such problems can be a real hard-brainer so lets try to collect all pieces before going deeper.

- I guess you do not really try to access some files directly on "C:\", am i right?
- Can you give us some code?
- Are you using the [DeploymentItem] attribute (right)?
- Do you have the right write privileges onto the directory you are trying to access?
- Are you targeting the right version of the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework". Compare the string you are using in the App.config with the version displayed in the propoerties windows when inspecting the according reference in your solution.
- Try to run the following command from the console in your debug directory:

> "PATHTOVSTEST\vstools.console.exe" yourtest.dll you.exe

I've found the executable here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\

Let us know if anything of the suggested things got you closer to a solution.